# PHP & MySQL question user submitted data?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how can I allow users to enter HTML and CSS to the there profiles safely using PHP and MySQL like they do on MySpace.

Answer (score 6):

You certainly want to carefully sanitize the data and limit it to a set of "unharmful" statements. E.g. http://htmlpurifier.org/ can help you with that.

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant 
>   HTML filter library written in 
>   PHP. HTML Purifier will not only remove all malicious 
>   code (better known as XSS) with a thoroughly audited, 
>   secure yet permissive whitelist,
>   it will also make sure your documents are 
>   standards compliant

When you put the data into the database use [prepared statements](http://de.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or carefully escape the data.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two things to consider :

- safely saving the HTML data into the database
- safely outputing the HTML data on the page.

For the first point, you must **avoid [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection)**.

This can be done by escaping your string data, before injecting it into your insert query, with functions such as [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), or [`PDO::quote`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php), depending on the API you are using.

Also, you might be interested by Prepared Statements ; see [`PDO::prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), or [`mysqli_prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

For the second point, what matters is **only allowing HTML tags and attributes that you consider as *safe***.

This can be done using a tool such as **[HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)**, to filter out all bad/non-accepted tags and attributes, and only keep the subset you whish to allow.

For example, if you consider the following HTML input :

```
<p>hello, world !</p>
<script type="text/javascript">alert('bad');</script>
<strong>this is <em>some text</strong></em>
```

HTMLPurifier will transform / purify it to :

```
<p>hello, world !</p>
<strong>this is <em>some text</em></strong>
```

Note that :

- the `<script>` tag has been removed
- the `<em>` and `<strong>` tags have been put back in the right order, making the HTML XHTML valid.

Comment: Everyone who mention mysql escaping, always fail to mention the second part - quoting. While without quotes *_escape_string will help nothing. So, many people start to believe that escaping does some magic "sanitization", to protect your database. While it's not sanitization nor protection at all but merely syntax rule and nothing else. And even more people start to believe that only user input must be escaped while it's not true and terrible mistake: every string data goes to the query must be escaped, no matter where it come from. And nobody cares that escaping won't help with LIMIT params

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, since escaping escapes quotes also, please explain your point further by explaining what you mean when you say "without quotes *_escape_string will help nothing". Do you have an example? Thank you.

Comment: @Marcus that's from mysql syntax. Data going to be distinguished from the operators by using quotes. `UPDATE table SET name='C\'tulhu'`. Note surrounding quotes which aren't escaped. Without these quotes there will be a parse error. So, every literal escaped with *_escape_string must be enclosed in quotes. In case when you cant use quotes (e.g. LIMIT arguments), escaping going to be useless and help nothing.